# from movieclip (check if main timeline is playing) in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, program-entry-point, timeline

i have this function, but ......
i want
 if the main time is playing so it go to the frame  and play
and
 if the main time is (not playing)  so it go to the frame  and pause

this function for a custom slider control in the main time.

thanks;

```
sliderLine_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,snapTO);

function snapTO(event:MouseEvent)

{
    if (sliderTrack.mouseX > 0 && sliderTrack.mouseX < 320)
    {
        sliderKnob.x = mouseX;
        sliderKnob.x = MovieClip(root).currentFrame * (300 / MovieClip(root).totalFrames);


        if (MovieClip(root).isPlaying == true)
        {
            MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(Math.floor(mouseX / (300/MovieClip(root).totalFrames))-60);

        }
        else if (MovieClip(root).isPlaying == false)
        {
            MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(Math.floor(mouseX / (300/MovieClip(root).totalFrames))-60);

        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a watcher movie clip that will do what you want:

```
public class WatcherMC extends MovieClip
{

private var last_enter_frame:int= 0;
private var root_animation_steps:int= 0;
private var root_stoped_steps:int= 0;
public RootIsPlaying:boolean= false;
public function WatcherMC():void 
{
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}


private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    if (MovieClip(root).currentFrame!= last_enter_frame)
    {

        root_animation_steps++;
        if (root_animation_steps> 3)
        {
                    root_stoped_steps= 0;  

                    root_is_playing();
        }
    }
    else
    {
             root_stoped_steps++;

             if (root_stoped_steps> 3)
             {
            root_animation_steps= 0;
            root_is_still_not_playing();
             }
    }
        last_enter_frame= MovieClip(root).currentFrame;
}


private function root_is_playing():void
{
// root is playing, do what ever I want
RootIsPlaying= true;
}
private function root_is_still_not_playing():void
{
// root is not playing, do what ever I want
RootIsPlaying= false;
}
```

}

put your code in the functions `root_is_playing` and `root_is_still_not_playing`
you can then check WatcherMC_instance.RootIsPlaying or not if you instantiate an instance of WatcherMC movie clip ..

like this:

```
var WatcherMC_instance:WatcherMC= new WatcherMC();
// use WatcherMC_instance.RootIsPlaying ..
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: sorry i am beginner and i didnot understand you, sorry... i need a simple idea if the main time line working go to frame and work and if the main time line not working go to and stop.... simple idea for smile slider....thanks again